# list card with header footer angular ionic

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

my problem is simple i just want to create list card with item array from controller.but im confused how to arrange my data to html. my list card consist of header,content,footer. i have trying every scenario how to put in data into list card 
here is my **controller**

```
.controller("homeController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.data = {};
 var diagramlink = 'http://fendypradana.com/alfalahkeu/Apifalah/infobayar/format/json';

            var processed_json = [], kategori = [],pembayaran_jumlah=[],sisa=[],jenisbayar_ket=[],statusbayar=[];
            $http.post(diagramlink, { user_id: 4 }).then(function (res) {
for (i = 0; i < res.data.data.length; i++) {
                    var dataint = parseInt(res.data.data[i].bayar_jumlah)
                    processed_json.push(dataint);
                    // processed_json.push(res.data.data[i].total);
                    kategori.push(res.data.data[i].pembayaran_tanggal);
                    pembayaran_jumlah.push(res.data.data[i].pembayaran_jumlah);
                    sisa.push(res.data.data[i].sisa);
                    jenisbayar_ket.push(res.data.data[i].jenisbayar_ket);
                    statusbayar.push(res.data.data[i].statusbayar);

                }
                $scope.bayar_jumlah=processed_json
                $scope.pembayaran_tanggal=kategori
                $scope.pembayaran_jumlah=pembayaran_jumlah
                $scope.sisa=sisa
                $scope.jenisbayar_ket=jenisbayar_ket
                $scope.statusbayar=statusbayar
   })

    })
```

and this is my html

```
<div class="item item-divider">
    {{stooge}}
</div>
<div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="tanggal in pembayaran_tanggal track by $index">
    {{tanggal}}
</div>
<div class="item item-divider" ng-repeat="status in statusbayar track by $index">
    {{status}}
</div>
            </div>
```

i have trying this one but its display each data array in my list. what im supossed to do is every data have a header,content,and footer itself.Any suggestions would really help.

**EDIT**

i want to put my data into list like this
http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#card-headers-footers

Comment: I do not understand is that you want a card list with Header, content and footer for each NG-REPEAT element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be true

```
<div ng-repeat="tanggal in array.pembayaran_tanggal track by $index" style="margin-top:10px">
    <div class="item item-divider">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="item item-text-wrap" >
        {{tanggal}}
    </div>
    <div class="item item-divider">
        {{array.statusbayar[$index]}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.array = {};
var diagramlink = 'http://fendypradana.com/alfalahkeu/Apifalah/infobayar/format/json';

        var processed_json = [], kategori = [],pembayaran_jumlah=[],sisa=[],jenisbayar_ket=[],statusbayar=[];
        $http.post(diagramlink, { user_id: 4 }).then(function (res) {
        for (i = 0; i < res.data.data.length; i++) {
                var dataint = parseInt(res.data.data[i].bayar_jumlah)
                processed_json.push(dataint);
                // processed_json.push(res.data.data[i].total);
                kategori.push(res.data.data[i].pembayaran_tanggal);
                pembayaran_jumlah.push(res.data.data[i].pembayaran_jumlah);
                sisa.push(res.data.data[i].sisa);
                jenisbayar_ket.push(res.data.data[i].jenisbayar_ket);
                statusbayar.push(res.data.data[i].statusbayar);

            }
            $scope.array.bayar_jumlah  = processed_json;
            $scope.array.pembayaran_tanggal = kategori;
            $scope.array.pembayaran_jumlah = pembayaran_jumlah;
            $scope.array.sisa = sisa;
            $scope.array.jenisbayar_ket = jenisbayar_ket;
            $scope.array.statusbayar = statusbayar;
   })
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/gwXZEm)